# Does a true Star Topology exist?

Tags: networking, switch

In Mike Meyers [A+ CompTIA book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/007179512X), he defines the star topology as a network where all units connect to some central wiring point - I image many units connected to a switch.

He then goes on to say that a network with many units connected to a switch are using a Star-Bus topology with the bus-portion being the line of ports on the switch.

If this is the case, what would a *true* star topology be if a "switch network" is not one.

Comment: That seems to be a nit-picking distinction (i.e. dissecting the internals of the "star" seems over-analytical when considering the broader topology).  Well, if you replace the switch with a hub, you might have what you're looking for, but with a severe performance penalty.

Comment: You might be asking a concept versus perfect-implementation question.  E.g. a multi-client/single-server model could exist as a star topology at the application layer or host perspective, and ignore the interconnecting units such as switches and routers, which would render the connections to be hopelessly complex and without structure if everything is added to the topology.